# Connecting an almost idempotent complex matrix to a diagonal 1-0 matrix

Tags: matrices, connectedness

$\newcommand{\diag}{\operatorname{diag}}$Let $e\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ be an almost idempotent matrix in the sense that $\|e^2-e\|<\varepsilon<\frac{1}{4}$ where the norm is taken to be the usual operator norm, and also $\|e\|\leq N$ (where $N>1$). I want to connect $e$ to a matrix of the form $\diag(I_k,0_{n-k})$ (if it is possible) via a path $(e_t)$ such that for each $t$, $\|e_t^2-e_t\|<\varepsilon$ (or $<4\varepsilon$) and $\|e_t\|\leq N$ (or $\leq 4N$).

By functional calculus, we can get an idempotent $p$ (i.e. $p^2=p$) out of $e$. 
One source of information on functional calculus for matrices is [An Elementary Approach to the Functional Calculus for Matrices](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2323606?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). The $k$ in the first paragraph is the rank of $p$.

I can do it in the case where $e$ is self-adjoint by first connecting $e$ to $p$, and then it is quite straightforward to connect $p$ to the desired matrix. In this case, all eigenvalues of $e$ are real with some of them close to 0 and the remaining ones close to 1. Those close to 0 can be connected to 0 by a path of real numbers, and those close to 1 can be connected to 1. I can write $e=uDu^*$ where $u$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal with diagonal entries being the eigenvalues of $e$. I can connect $D$ to a matrix of the form $\diag(I_k,0_{n-k})$ by connecting each diagonal entry to 0 or 1. Thus I can connect $e$ to its associated idempotent, which in this case is precisely $u\diag(I_k,0_{n-k})\;u^*$.

But I haven't been able to do it without self-adjointness.

Comment: I don't follow. Consider the scalar case with $0\approx e\in\mathbb R$ and $k=1$, i.e. we want to connect $e_0\approx0$ to $e_1=1$. When $\varepsilon$ is very close to zero, the constraint that $\|e_t^2-e_t\|<\varepsilon$ would force each $e_t$ to be either close to zero or close to one. Therefore the construction of a continuous path from $e_0$ to $e_1$ is not possible without violating the given constraint. Did I miss something?

Comment: In this case, I think $p=0$ so $k=0$ and we actually want to connect $e$ to 0.

Comment: Do you mean the target rank $k$ is not prespecified, and you just want to connect $e$ to some $I_k\oplus0_{(n-k)\times(n-k)}$?

Comment: $k$ is prespecified. It is the rank of the idempotent obtained from $e$, which may be different from the rank of $e$ itself, like in your example.