# Path connectedness of $SL_n(C)$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, complex-analysis

Prove that $SL_n(C)$ is path connected. We need a continuous path joining any two points in $SL_n(C).$ Let $A,B\in SL_n(C)$ be any two points. Then can anyone give a path define $\gamma:[0,1]\to SL_n(C)$ such that $\gamma(0)=A, \gamma(1)=B.$

Comment: forget about path for some time. Given two matrices from special linear group can you produce another matrix from special linear group? Do you know more such?

Comment: $\textrm{SL}_2(\Bbb C)$ is generated by elementary matrices.

Comment: I recommend first finding a path $\gamma : [0, 1]\to \text{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ between $I_n$ and arbitrary $A\in \text{SL}_n(\mathbb{C})$, and then taking the path $\gamma_1$ from $I_n$ to $A$ and the path $\gamma_2$ from $I_n$ to $B$, and consider $\gamma(t) = \gamma_1(1-t)\gamma_2(t)$.

Comment: @MichaelLee I doubt that this hint would make the problem easier..

Comment: [On the contrary...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139549/how-to-show-path-connectedness-of-gln-mathbbc)

Comment: Alternatively, there is an explanation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group#Topology) of why the special linear group is even simply connected (which of course implies that it is path connected).

Comment: I tried as your suggestion, but not succeeded to find such path. Please help with the proper path.