# Can we continously map coefficients of characteristic polynomials to matrices with specified endpoints?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, general-topology, polynomials

Let $A_1, A_2 \in \mathcal M_n(\mathbb C)$ be two fixed matrices with characteristic polynomials
\begin{align*}
&p_{A_1}(t) = t^n + \alpha_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \dots + \alpha_0, \\
&p_{A_2}(t) = t^{n} + \beta_{n-1}t^{n-1} + \dots + \beta_0.
\end{align*}
There is a bijection $\pi$ between $\mathbb C^n$ and the set of monic polynomials in degree $n$, i.e., $\pi(\alpha_{n-1}, \dots, \alpha_0) = t^n + \alpha_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \dots + \alpha_0$.
Let $\gamma: [0,1] \to \mathbb C^n$ be a continuous path with $\gamma(0) = (\alpha_{n-1} , \dots, \alpha_0)$ and $\gamma(1) = (\beta_{n-1}, \dots, \beta_0)$. Does there exist a continuous function $f: [0,1] \to \mathcal M_n(\mathbb C)$ with $f(0) = A_1, f(1)=A_2$ such that $p_{f(s)} (t) = \pi(\gamma(s))$ for every $s \in [0,1]$ where $p_{f(s)}(t)$ denotes the characteristic polynomial of $f(s)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using [Companion Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Let $\pi_k$ be the projection map from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}$ that projects to the $k^{\textrm{th}}$ coordinate.

Consider the following path in the space $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$:

$$f(s) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -\pi_{n}(\gamma (s)) \\
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & -\pi_{n-1}(\gamma (s)) \\
0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & -\pi_{n-2}(\gamma (s))  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & -\pi_{1}(\gamma (s))
\end{bmatrix}$$

Then each f(s) is a companion matrix for $\pi(\gamma (s))$ and so has that polynomial as its characteristic polynomial. This function is continuous since every entry of the matrix is either constant or the negative of one of the components of the continuous path $\gamma$.

Edit: After thinking about this some more, in order to get a path from arbitrary $A_1$ to $A_2$, we'll need to use the [Jordan Normal Form Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) instead. By that theorem, there exists invertible matrices $S_1$ and $S_2$ in $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ such that:

$$A_1 = S_1 \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_{1} & \epsilon_{1} & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_{2} & \epsilon_{2} & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_{3} & \dots & 0 & 0  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0  & 0 & \dots & \lambda_{n-1} & \epsilon_{n-1} \\
0 & 0  & 0 & \dots & 0 & \lambda_n
\end{bmatrix} S_1^{-1}$$

where the $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues, the $\epsilon_{i} \in \{0,1\}$, and a similar form exists for $S_2$.

Since $GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ is [path-connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139549/how-to-show-path-connectedness-of-gln-mathbbc), there is a continuous path $S(s)$ from $S_1$ to $S_2$ that stays in $GL(n,\mathbb{C}$).

Now, for every $s \in [0,1]$, use the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to factor the polynomial $$\pi(\gamma(s)) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} (t-\lambda_i(s)).$$

Now, the roots of a polynomial vary continuously in terms of their coefficients. One way to make this precise is [this paper by Naulin and Pabst](http://bdigital.unal.edu.co/33590/1/33465-124138-1-PB.pdf). In particular, by always using a lexicographical ordering of $\mathbb{C}$ when writing our roots, we get $n$ continuous functions $\lambda_i(s)$ that maintain that order. We now adopt the convention that whenever writing Jordan normal forms, our eigenvalues will also be ordered lexicographically. (This convention can easily be used in picking $S_1$ and $S_2$ above.)

Next, we need to deal with the $\epsilon_i$'s. Look at the Jordan normal forms for $A_1$ and $A_2$ (as always with eigenvalues ordered lexicographically). Let $\epsilon_{j,i}$ be the $(i,i+1)$ entry of $A_j$. Then define the following continuous paths:

$$E_i(s) = \begin{cases} s, & \textrm{if } \epsilon_{1,i} = 0 \textrm{ and } \epsilon_{2,i} = 1 \\ 1-s, & \textrm{if }  \epsilon_{1,i} = 1 \textrm{ and } \epsilon_{2,i} = 0 \\ 1, & \textrm{if } \epsilon_{1,i} = \epsilon_{2,i} = 1 \\ 0, & \textrm{if } \epsilon_{1,i} = \epsilon_{2,i} = 0 \end{cases}$$

Finally (!), we're ready to put these all together to get our path:

$$f(s) = S(s) \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_{1}(s) & E_1(s) & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_{2}(s) & E_2(s) & \dots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \lambda_{3}(s) & \dots & 0 & 0  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0  & 0 & \dots & \lambda_{n-1}(s) & E_{n-1}(s)  \\
0 & 0  & 0 & \dots & 0 & \lambda_n(s)
\end{bmatrix} S(s)^{-1}$$

This is a continuous path in $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, $f(0) = A_1$, $f(1) = A_2$, and the characterisitic polynomial of $f(s)$ is (by similarity and properities of upper triangular matrices) $$\prod_{i=1}^{n} (t-\lambda_i(s)) = \pi(\gamma(s)).$$

Comment: In your construction, $f(0) \neq A_1$ and $f(1) \neq A_2$.

Comment: I see that. I'm thinking on it.

Comment: Maybe you can find continuous $P(t)$ so that $P(0)f(0)P(0)^{-1} = A_{1}$ and $P(1)f(1)P(1)^{-1} = A_{2}$?

Comment: See my comment on the other answer. This doesn't work if A1 and A2 don't have structurally the same rational canonical forms.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think it's complete and correct now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's note that this question is subtle, because the answer is no over $\mathbb{R}$! The matrices 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0&1 \\ -1&0 \end{bmatrix} \ \mbox{and}\ \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1 \\ 1&0 \end{bmatrix}$$
both have characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2+1$, but there is no path from one to the other through matrices with characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2+1$. To see this, note that a upper triangular matrix cannot have characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2+1$, so it is not possible to continuously change from lower left entry negative to lower left entry positive while keeping the same characteristic polynomial.

However, the original question was over $\mathbb{C}$, and there the answer is yes. As in Charlie Cunninham's answer, for a degree $n$ polynomial $p$, let $C(p)$ be the companion matrix. We can write our original matrices as $A_1 = S_1 C(p_1) S_1^{-1}$ and $A_2 = S_2 C(p_2) S_2^{-1}$ for some invertible $S_1$ and $S_2$. The group $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is path connected ([here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~josephbreen/Path_Connectedness_and_Invertible_Matrices.pdf) is the first citation I could find) so we can build a path $S(t)$ from $S_1$ to $S_2$. Then $S(t) C(p_{\gamma(t)}) S(t)^{-1}$ is your desired path.

Comment: I forgot one subtle point that bugged me before: what if the polynomial is not square-free at the start and end points? In this case, $A_1, A_2$ are not necessarily similar to their companion forms.

Comment: To add on to the OP's comment, I tried this method before, and it didn't work because matrices are only similar to their rational canonical forms, which might not be companion matrices. Companion Matrices all have the characteristic and minimal polynomial equal, which is not true for all matrices. If A1 and A2 have structurally different rational canonical forms, I can't necessarily find a path between them, but neither can I find an invariant to distinguish them.

Comment: You are right. The ugly solution would be to replace rational canonical form with Jordan normal form, use implicit function theorem to express the roots as continuous functions of the coefficients of the polynomial, and do something hackish with the off diagonal entries. But I don't see all the details here and there should be a shorter way.

Comment: I tried that too, but couldn't get the details of the off-diagonal entries to work out. Let me know if you figure it out! (Or an easier way.)

Comment: Would you mind providing outlines of your idea? I could not see a clear way to make everything work out. Thanks.

Comment: If you look at my edited answer, I think I've figured out all the fiddly details.