# Question on path connectedness of two invertible matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, representation-theory, path-connected

Suppose that $A_1 , A_2 \in M_n (\mathbb C)$ are invertible matrices.  
**Claim:** There exists finitely many complex numbers $z\in \mathbb C$ such that $f(t) :=\det(zA_1+ (1-z)A_2)=0.$ Which is true via Fundamental theorem of algebra. Now define
$$\gamma:[0,1]\longrightarrow \mathbb C.$$
Would it easily follow by the construction above that there exists a continuous path $\varphi(z)$ of the form $$\varphi(z)= \gamma(z) A_1 +(1-\gamma(z))A_2$$ connecting $A_1$ to $A_2$? 
Any help and hints would be so much appreciated!

Comment: Did you mean to write $(1 - γ(z)) A_2$ instead of the current $(1 - γ(z) A_2)$ in the formula vor $φ$?

Comment: The answers on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/139549/1104384) should help.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner yes sorry for the typo error.

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks! I don't understand the argument, we can find a path $\gamma\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb C$ is this immediate?

Comment: @TokitaOhma See the accepted answer on the post. To reframe the argument into your context: the set of $t$ for which $f(t) = 0$ is finite, and it follows that there is a path $\gamma:[0,1] \to \Bbb C$ from $1$ to $0$ in $\Bbb C$ such that  $f(\gamma(t)) \neq 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: I think you mean $A_1 , A_2 \in GL_n (\mathbb C)$. Everything in $M_n (\mathbb C)$ is trivially path connected (e.g. to the zero matrix).

Comment: @BenGrossmann sorry I still can't reason out why would it follow that there is a path $\gamma:[0,1] \to \Bbb C$ is this because $f(t)=0$ is finite? Would finiteness of $0$ would easily follow the existence of path connectedness?

Comment: The standard approach in a complex analysis text: consider some finite set $S$.  Then it's immediate that $\mathbb C-S$ is open; prove it is connected.  Now prove (/ use the fact) that open and connected implies path connected in a metric space (locally path connected).  It's worthwhile to compare this with $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Tokita It follows from the fact that **the set of $z \in \Bbb C$ for which $f(z) = 0$** is finite. I'm not sure what you have in mind when you say "$f(t) = 0$ is finite" or "finiteness of $0$".