# Neighborhood in orthogonal group

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, topological-groups, orthogonal-matrices

Let $A\in O(n)$. Assume that $|a_{i,i}|\neq 1$ for every $i$. Prove that in every neighborhood of $A$ there exists $B\in O(n)$ such that
$|b_{i,i}|>|a_{i,i}| \text{ for every } i \text{ and } |b_{i,j}|\leq |a_{i,j}| \text{ for every } i\neq j$.

I have thought about projecting $A+\epsilon I$ on $O(n)$ (wlog I assume $a_{ii}\geq 0$ here), but there doesn't seem to be a nice formula indicating whether this projection would work or not. Similarly I am not sure about Gram-Schmidt. Or maybe it's better to find a prove that doesn't use explicit constructions, but I don't know much about neighborhood in $O(n)$. Any suggestions?

Edit: the main difficulty I faced was that, if $a_{i,j}=0$ then we must force $b_{i,j}=0$, which prevents methods that involve 'small perturbation of every entry'.

Edit 2: As a counter-example is given below, I wonder whether the claim is true if $A$ is close to $I$, say if $A$ is closest to $I$ among all signed permutation matrices. (In the counter-example, $A\neq I$ itself is a signed permutation matrix).

Note that this claim is true is $A$ is close enough to $I$, as we can form a path $B_t=\text{exp}(t\log(A))$. Since the entries of $B_t$ is analytic on $t$, if $A$ is sufficiently close to $I$ every $B_t$ would satisfy the conditions for $t\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 4):

This is not always possible. As you have already discovered, a difficulty is that all off-diagonal zeroes in $A$ must be inherited by $B$. For instance, consider
$$
A=\pmatrix{\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{1}&0\\ 0&\color{red}{0}&\color{red}{1}\\ \color{red}{1}&0&\color{red}{0}}.
$$
Only the red elements are modifiable. As the rows and columns of $B$ are unit vectors, we must have
$$
B=\pmatrix{c&s&0\\ 0&\pm c&\pm s\\ \pm s&0&\pm c}
$$
for some real numbers $c$ and $s$ such that $c^2+s^2=1$. But then the first two columns of $B$ are orthogonal to each other only when $c=0$ or $s=0$ (so that $c=\pm1$). Therefore, $c$ cannot be a small nonzero number and $B$ does not exist in any small neighbourhood of $A$.

Comment: You would have different angles for each column?

Comment: @ArcticChar You cannot. The rows of $B$ are unit vectors too. (Strictly speaking, you can have different angles -- just take $-\theta$ instead of $\theta$ for instance -- but the values of $|\sin\theta|$ and $|\cos\theta|$ must remain the same.)

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for your answer! See the edits on the question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case when $A$ is in [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Canonical_form):

$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{cccccc}R_{1} & & & & & \\ & \ddots & & & & 0 \\ & & R_{K} & & & \\ & & & \pm 1 & & \\ & 0 & & & & \ddots \\ & & & & & \pm 1\end{array}\right]
\qquad
R_k = \left[\begin{array}{rr}\cos(\theta_k) & -\sin(\theta_k) \\ \sin(\theta_k) & \cos(\theta_k)\end{array}\right]
$$

Here, the claim is obviously true: We can increase the size of the diagonal entries, while reducing the size of the off-diagonal entries by undoing the rotations. All that's left to is to extend this argument to the general case.

Comment: So for a general $B\in O(n)$, there exists $P\in O(n)$ and $A$ in canonical form you gave such that $B=PAP^T$. Are you claiming that if we increase the size of the diagonal entries, while reducing the size of the off-diagonal entries, then such phenomenon also happens on $B$? Could you hint me why this is true? I can only see that the size of the diagonal entries of $B$ indeed increase.

Comment: @LoCelso, no I am not claiming that. Obviously this is not a complete answer but rather an idea of how to approach the question. The key ingredient is that you can apply Given's Rotations with small angle, which give you some control over the matrix entries while staying in an arbitrarily small neighbourhood. You could try to use this idea to construct a path from $A$ to a diagonal matrix, similarly as done here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1794563/99220. The hope would be that along the path, the magnitudes of the entries change monotonically.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! But I have found two difficulties: first, finding paths envolves a change of basis, which I couldn't do since it would destroy the size of the entries; second, finding paths row by row would affect other rows' size of the entries, so it seems like I couldn't find some intermediate points and join them by paths.

Comment: @LoCelso Hey just a reminder: to avoid getting "wrong" answers like this, formulate your question properly! When you write `Prove that [...]` then I automatically presuppose that the statement is true and that you are looking for a way to prove it. When you don't know whether the statement is true or not then it is usually better to formulations like `Is it true that ...` or `Is it always possible to ...`