# Prove it is locally connected topological group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

I got stuck on the following problem:

I am looking at the general linear group $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ which is a subset of $\Bbb R^{n^2}$. I want now to prove that $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ is a locally connected topological group, without the fact that it is locally compact.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in two steps:

1. $GL_n(\mathbb R)$, regarded as a subset of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$, is an open subset, as one proves using continuity of the determinant function $\text{det} : \mathbb R^{n^2} \to \mathbb R$
2. Every open subset of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ is locally connected, as one proves using the standard "open ball" basis for the topology on $\mathbb R^{n^2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't see how the continuity helps me out in point 1....

Comment: Continuity of a function is equivalent to saying that the inverse image of an open set is open. $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is by definition the subset of $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ defined by $\text{det}(M) \ne 0$, and therefore $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is the inverse image, under the continuous function $\text{det}$, of the open subset $\mathbb R - \{0\} \subset \mathbb R$.

Comment: Thank you a lot! The seconde point is clear. Now I have a seconde question, I know that  $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ has two connected components:  $GL_n^+(\Bbb R)$ and  $GL_n^-(\Bbb R)$ but here again I got stuck the show this.

Comment: That's perhaps a good followup question. But, rather than ask it here in a comment to an answer to this post, where few other than you or I will know about it, you should ask it in a new post.

Comment: Of course, thanks for everything!

Comment: Although, a little searching led me to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100978/how-many-connected-components-does-mathrmgl-n-mathbb-r-have) in which your latest question is asked and answered completely.